# M-x gdb don't create new frames

Tags: gdb

When I run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`gdb`, Emacs opens a new frame with the code being debugged.  This is while having two buffers open in the original frame: the one with debugger's console and another one with the program's output.

## Question

Is it possible to not open this extra frame?

Comment: I have only played around a little with gdb, but I see that I previously customized the variable `gdb-display-buffer-other-frame-action` to use a custom function that targets an existing frame or creates a new one depending upon my preferences.  `(setq gdb-display-buffer-other-frame-action '(my-custom-display-buffer-function))`.  The default behavior appears to be set up like one of the examples in the manual -- scroll down to the very bottom of the page for some ideas on how to customize it:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html

Comment: @lawlist Yeah, that worked. Thank you! I'll need some more tuning to get both output and source buffers to be displayed exactly the way I need, but, at least, I could put them all in the same frame.